# Why is this saying that the object is not subscriptable (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that will detect if a list is a palindrome. Here is what I have so far-

```
##theSubList = raw_input("Input the list here")
def isPalindrome( theSubList ) :
    return theSubList == theSubList[::-1]
```

Why does this tell me that the "int" object is not subscriptable. The only way I can get this to run is by putting the top line in (the commented out part) but I don't want to have to do that, everything should come from just the isPalindrome( theSubList ).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Show the rest of your code. What you posted works fine.

Comment: Could you include the rest of your code, including your call to your function `isPalindrome`? It looks like you're passing some kind of number when you should be passing something else.

Comment: Here is the error I get when I try to run it-isPalindrome(123454321)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
    isPalindrome(123454321)
  File "C:\Users\wbentley\Documents\Mines\Comp Sci\Python\Palindrome.py", line 19, in isPalindrome
    return theSubList == theSubList[::-1]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Nothing smells like homework.

Comment: That error is most likely cause you're passing it a value for theSubList that is unsubscriptable.  In other words...  You need to show us the rest of your code, including where the function is called.

Comment: Huh? It is homework. I don't want anyone to write the code for me, just point me in the right direction from here

Comment: @hochl  Could also be project euler.  ;)

Comment: I added a solution for strings, so now go out and try it for lists :-) Don't forget to reward the effort ^^

Answer (score 2):

In your comment, you've posted that your call to the function is `isPalindrome(123454321)`, which is calling your function on a number. You need to call it on a string.  Change your call to `isPalindrome('123454321')` and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. This programming stuff is hard. Now I've just got to figure out the rest of the stuff on this assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like:

```
def isPalindrome(a):
    return a == "".join(reversed(a))
```

This is for strings, so `isPalindrome('otto')` is `True`.